# Cannot read property 'setData' of undefined - React touch event

Tags: reactjs, redux, touch-event

My touch function definition is

```
onDragStart(ev,id) {
    console.log('dragstart: ',id)
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("id",id)
}
onTouchStart(ev,id) {
    console.log('touchstart: ',id)
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("id",id)
}
```

Here the console gives `touchstart: 9824357` correctly, but the next line gives `Cannot read property 'setData' of undefined`. This codes works fine for onDragStart.

My div is

```
<div 
    onDragStart={(e)=>this.onDragStart(e, id)}  
    onTouchStart={(e)=>this.onTouchStart(e, id)}
    draggable                    
    className="draggable">                    
</div>
```

How can I fix this? Should I add or declare anything more for touch events?

Comment: give us full working snippet

Comment: I have added the onDragStart function which is a working snippet for drag event

Comment: Add full source-code because I might have error elsewhere

Answer (score 2):

The [`touchstart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/touchstart) dom event does not have `dataTransfer` property. It's not a drag-and-drop event. To fix this, remove the line     `ev.dataTransfer.setData("id",id)`, since there's no [`DataTransfer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer) happening with touch events.

Comment: Can you suggest a function or property instead of dataTransfer?

Comment: No I can't. I have no idea what your goal is with this code. From what you have told us, I can only tell you why your code throws an exception.

Comment: My goal is just to get the vaalue in my drop event as `let id = ev.dataTransfer.getData("id");`

Comment: If you are using redux, then dispatch an action instead. Why do you think it's a good idea to monkeypatch dom events?

Answer (score 2):

As has been told, `dataTransfer` is not a property for touch events.

Instead you can use `ev.target` for extracting the info of the touched element and then point to the property you want to transfer (in your case the id)
In your example:

In HTML just add an id to your draggable element:

```
<div class="draggable" id="_draggable">                    
</div>
```

In JS:

```
let box = document.querySelector(".draggable");


box.addEventListener('touchmove', (e) => {
    //Gets movement in px of the touch movement
    let touchLocation = e.targetTouches[0];
    //Gets element data
    currentElement = e.target;
    //Gets element id
    currentElementId = currentElement.id;

    //Moves element
    box.style.left = touchLocation.pageX + 'px';
    box.style.top = touchLocation.pageY + 'px';
})



box.addEventListener('touchend', (e) => {
    //Picks up the id of the dragged element
    console.log(currentElementId)

    //Picks up the new element position
    let x = parseInt(box.style.left);
    let y = parseInt(box.style.top);

})
```

Also remember that the element to be dragged must have `position: absolute;`